# Bootstrap menu interaction

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have used this example from Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/ and worked fine. Since I have added a my left menu (it appears when you leftclick) the color of Bootstrap top menu changed like you can see here: http://www.felpone.netsons.org/web-threejs/stereos%20-%20Copia.html
 now is not black like before. I cannot solve it.

Comment: So what's the question here?

Comment: If you want a black navbar see my answer

Comment: Please post your code in the question instead of just linking to outside sources.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-inverse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have CSS which sets the background color of all `.container`s to `#F3EFE0`. Either remove or reduce the scope of that css rule or apply a new rule to the navbar container to override it.

CSS

```
.navbar-fixed-top > .container { background-color:#333; }
```

Additionally, I'm not quite sure why you are using a `.container` in the navbar. It doesn't require it. You can simply remove it and it will also resolve the issue.